# Which is best way to design UI for android (Coding or Drag & Drop)?

Tags: android

I'm learning Android development in Android Studio. My question is that what is the best way to make UI for Android apps. I'm right now learning coding to make the UI of apps. It's a hard or time-consuming process but I find that this is another way to create UI of Android apps via the drag or drop feature. So, I want to ask which one should I choose to create UI of apps ?? because I want to work as an Android Develper.
Thanks yo

Comment: Go with code and don't look back, I'll suggest learn and master `ConstraintLayout` then its animator `MotionLayout` using code. Also, learn basics about other layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag and drop are useful when you don't have to make a good/presentable UI, You are just in hurry to check/test something. But for long term or to make reliable UI, I'd suggest you go with writing code in XML. This helps you understand the concept of how things stick to each other and you can make changes easily when needed. All the best.
Try [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) ,It's very flexible and will help you understand the concept of constraints.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to become an Android developer, you have to practice a lot, the drag and drop feature on the `xml` layout design is very useful, but it would be nice if you also have to master the attributes and components in the Android layout. It depends on usage, but I would rather write the `xml` code directly to better understand the points of layout on Android. **Keep learning and keep up spirit**

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand your concept.